# Ordenar collection de produtos intercalando conforme flag

Tags: php, laravel, classificação, collection

Tenho uma model chamada `Product` que possui, além dos dados do produtos, uma flag `featured` que diz se o produtos é destaque ou não. Na hora de montar a view os produtos devem ser exibidos conforme a seguinte estrutura HTML: https://jsfiddle.net/efhhnbsj/1/

Conforme pode ser visto o produto com a flag `featured` possui uma grid maior. Já tentei várias formas e não consigo encontrar uma lógica para isso, pois não achei um jeito de ordenar a collection de maneira que fique 1 produto em destaque seguido de 4 outros produtos sem destaque, assim por diante.

Alguém tem alguma luz?

Comment: Você está usando o blade nas views?

Comment: Você pode trazer dois arrays, um com os produtos em destaque e outro com os produtos normais, é fácil fazer isso com o eloquent, te pouparia um pouco de usar javascipt

Comment: @FelipePaetzold estou usando sim blade, eu pensei em fazer duas queries, uma para produtos em destaque e outra para os demais. Iria definir duas colunas e sempre colocaria os em destaque na direita, porém agora vi que vou precisar intercalar a posição do produto destaque também: https://jsfiddle.net/efhhnbsj/2/

Answer (score 2):

Ora bem, o meu conselho é trazeres dois conjuntos de resultados da base de dados, lembra-te que podes ordena-los quando os vais buscar à base de dados, ex: `...->orderBy('preco', 'DESC');`

```
$feat = Product::where('feature', 1)->get(); // array com os produtos featured
$no_feat = Product::where('feature', 0)->get(); // array com os produtos não featured
```

Depois seguindo a lógica em baixo, fazes:

```
$feat = ['featured', 'featured', 'featured']; // produtos featured
$no_feat = ['brrh', 'brrh', 'brrh', 'brrh','brrh', 'brrh', 'brrh', 'brrh', 'brrh', 'brrh', 'brrh', 'brrh', 'brrh', 'brrh', 'brrh', 'brrh']; // produtos não featured
$all = [];
$all_len = count($feat) + count($no_feat);
for($i = 0; $i < $all_len; $i++) {
    if($i%5 == 0 && count($feat) > 0) {
        $all[] = array_shift($feat);
        continue;
    }
    if(count($no_feat) > 0) {
        $all[] = array_shift($no_feat);
    }
    else {
        $all[] = array_shift($feat);
    }
}

echo '<pre>', print_r($all), '</pre>';
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => featured
    [1] => brrh
    [2] => brrh
    [3] => brrh
    [4] => brrh
    [5] => featured
    [6] => brrh
    [7] => brrh
    [8] => brrh
    [9] => brrh
    [10] => featured
    [11] => brrh
    [12] => brrh
    [13] => brrh
    [14] => brrh
    [15] => brrh
    [16] => brrh
    [17] => brrh
    [18] => brrh
)
```

No fim disto o arrays dos produtos declarados ao início, `$feat` e `$no_feat` vão estar vazios:

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](http://ideone.com/J0fY1Z)

Mas ao ver o teu jsfiddle:

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 featured"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <div class="col-xs-6 box"></div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 box green"></div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 box red"></div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 box blue"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

imagino que um array neste formato te dê mais jeito:

```
$feat = ['featured', 'featured', 'featured'];
$no_feat = ['brrh', 'brrh', 'brrh', 'brrh','brrh', 'brrh', 'brrh', 'brrh', 'brrh', 'brrh', 'brrh', 'brrh'];
$all = [];
$h = 0;
$all_len = count($feat) + count($no_feat);
for($i = 0; $i < $all_len; $i++) {
    if($i%5 == 0 && count($feat) > 0) {
        $all[] = array_shift($feat);
        $h++;
        continue;
    }
    if(count($no_feat) > 0) {
        $all['no_feat' .$h][] = array_shift($no_feat);
    }
    else {
        $all[] = array_shift($feat);
    }
}
echo '<pre>', print_r($all), '</pre>';
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => featured
    [no_feat1] => Array
        (
            [0] => brrh
            [1] => brrh
            [2] => brrh
            [3] => brrh
        )

    [1] => featured
    [no_feat2] => Array
        (
            [0] => brrh
            [1] => brrh
            [2] => brrh
            [3] => brrh
        )

    [2] => featured
    [no_feat3] => Array
        (
            [0] => brrh
            [1] => brrh
            [2] => brrh
            [3] => brrh
        )

)
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](http://ideone.com/kDEwzL)

Depois no blade podias fazer:

```
@foreach($all as $prod)
    @if(!is_array($prod))
        <div class="col-xs-6 featured"></div>;
        <?php continue; ?>
    @endif
    <div class="col-xs-6">;
    @foreach($prod as $no_feat_prod)
        <div class="col-xs-6 box no-featured"></div>
    @endforeach
    </div>
@endforeach
```